# What is the practical consequence of the message "unable to initialize frontend: Dialog" when installing packages in a non-standard shell?

Tags: software-installation, dialog, debconf

When I install some software packages from Emacs in a non-interactive shell, say from an `org-babel` file some of the packages result in the message below:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
```

I know that in the case of mysql for instance it is to prompt for  the root password, or some other stuff which the user's preferences or settings are sought.

I take it that in such cases the installer may use some default settings and continue.

So my main concerns are:

1. Can the consequences be that bad?
2. Are there some kind of response files related to each package that can be passed to the installer or some default files at some preset locations that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the messages you quoted, if the `Dialog` frontend cannot be used (e.g. when running the package installation commands from within Emacs), the package configuration system will use a simpler `Readline` frontend instead.

Practically that means, that instead of getting the preference questions individually in text boxes at the center of your screen, you'll get them as regular text, one after another, among other messages from `debconf`. It should be able to display all the same questions, they just look a bit different from what you may be used to. Your ways to edit what you've typed may also be more limited in some cases, i.e. arrow keys might not work, restricting you to just backspace only.

If the `Readline` frontend is not usable either, and there are no pre-configured settings for the package, then built-in defaults will be used instead. Only if the package has a setting with no corresponding default, the package installation may fail.

> 1. Can the consequences be that bad?

If you are not confused by the preference questions displayed in a different way, it's not so bad. Just be calm, read the messages the computer shows you, and you'll be able to figure it out.

> 2. Are there some kind of response files [...] ?

Yes, there are ways to automate the configuration. Make sure you have the `debconf-doc` package installed, then use `man 7 debconf` and read the paragraphs titled *Preconfiguring packages* and *Unattended package installation*.

Basically, if you have a package you have not installed yet, you can use

```
dpkg-preconfigure <package-name_version.deb>
```

to view and answer all the package's questions before the package is actually installed. After that (or in a system that already has that package installed), you can view the stored preferences with:

```
debconf-show <package-name>
```

You can then pick the settings you want stored in a file like this:

```
debconf-get-selections | grep <name of setting> >>settings.txt
```

Repeat as many times as needed, then transfer the settings file to another host and feed it into `debconf` with:

```
debconf-set-selections < settings.txt
```

Or just pipe it over SSH or whatever, e.g.:

```
ssh root@newhost debconf-set-selections < settings.txt
```

After that, when installing the package on host `newhost`, the answers to configuration questions are already supplied to `debconf`, so those questions won't be asked interactively. (If a newer version of a package has more questions, then only the new questions will be asked.)